# Projective dimension 2 and maps out of torsion module

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, projective-module

I've recently been learning some homological algebra, mainly out of Northcott and some other sources, and I'm having trouble with the notion of projective dimension. In particular, I have a question (not from Northcott) that says

> Let $R = k[x,y]$ for a field $k$ and $M$ a finitely generated $R$-module. Then $M$ has projective dimension $2$ if and only if $\text{Hom}_R(k,M) \neq 0$, where we consider $k$ as an $R$-module with the ideal $\mathfrak m=(x,y)$ acting as $0$ on $k$ (i.e. $k = R/\mathfrak m$).

I have attempted the problem but I don't see any of linking the notion of projective dimension to the Hom-set. What I have so far:

We have a projective resolution $$0\rightarrow P_2\rightarrow P_1\rightarrow P_0\rightarrow M\rightarrow 0$$ of $M$ and so we have a long exact sequence $$0\rightarrow \text{Hom}(k,P_2)\rightarrow \text{Hom}(k,P_1)\rightarrow \text{Hom}(k,P_0)\rightarrow \text{Hom}(k,M)\rightarrow \text{Ext}^1(k,P_2)\rightarrow \dots$$

We also have the exact sequence $$0\rightarrow \mathfrak m\rightarrow R\rightarrow k\rightarrow 0$$ which gives rise to the long exact sequence $$0\rightarrow \text{Hom}(k,M)\rightarrow \text{Hom}(R,M)\rightarrow \text{Hom}(\mathfrak m, M)\rightarrow \text{Ext}^1(k,M)\rightarrow \text{Ext}^1(R,M)\dots$$

Of these two long exact sequences I think the second one is more useful because we don't know anything about the $P_i$'s from the first one. Also $\text{Ext}^1(R,M) = 0$ since $R$ is projective, so we have an exact sequence with just four nonzero terms if we ignore everything past that.

However I have no idea how to include the projective resolution of $M$ which I imagine is necessary since the projective dimension of $M$ is a hypothesis. Also not sure how to use the finitely generated assumption.

So, I'd like a hint or two to proving this particular claim, and also if possible some general tips on proving things about projective dimension and using long exact sequences in general.

Comment: Do you know the homological description of the depth?

Comment: I've seen it in passing, something about the smallest $n$ for which $\text{Ext}^n(k, M) \neq 0$ right? or the smallest $n$ such that Ext is $0$.

Comment: Yes, it is the smallest $n$ for which the Ext is non-zero.

Comment: The assertion is false. I edited my answer and gave a counterexample. If you want it to be true, you have to state in the power series ring or the localization at some maximal ideal.

Comment: Is the assertion true if we add the condition that M be graded over R with the usual grading?

Comment: @IAlreadyHaveAKey, yes (but you need to change the condition to allow shifts of the module $k$) (For example, there is no nonzero map from $k$ to $k[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2)$, but there is one from the shift $k(1)$)

Comment: How do we see this? I think there is a graded version of the Auslander Buchsbaum formula from which this follows quite trivially, but how might one see it without the formula?

Answer (score 3):

A simpler way to see that the claim is false in one direction is to notice that the automorphism group of $R$ acts transitively on the set of modules of the form $R/(x-a,y-b)$, so that they all have the same projective dimension. As there are no nonzero maps between them, the claim is false.

---

Let's do the graded case. First, show that $\def\Ext{\operatorname{Ext}}\def\Tor{\operatorname{Tor}}\Ext^p(k,M)\cong \Tor_{2-p}(k,M)$ for all modules $M$, so that $\hom(k,M)=0$ implies that $\Tor_2(k,M)=0$. Now pick a projective resolution $0\to P_2\to P_1\to P_0\to M$ of $M$, and since $M$ is finitely generated, we can pick it so that it is *minimal*, that is, the image of each map $P_{i+1}\to P_i$ is in $R_+P_i$. As $\Tor(k,M)$ is the homology of the complex $0\to k\otimes P_2\to k\otimes P_1\to k\otimes P_0$ and the minimality of the resolution implies that all the maps here are zero, we see that $k\otimes P_2$ and this implies that $P_2=0$, by the graded Nakayama. It follows that $M$ has projective dimension at most $1$.

(Here the hypothesis is that $\hom(k,M)=0$, but that is an ungraded $\hom$: if we want to use a graded $\hom$ we have to have $\hom(k(\ell),M)=0$ for all shifts $\ell$.)

---

To check that $\Ext^p(k,M)\cong \Tor_{2-p}(k,M)$ notice that $k$ has the Koszul resolution $0\to R\otimes\Lambda^2V\to R\otimes V\to R\to k$, with $V$ the vector space with basis $\{x,y\}$. Use it to construct complexes which compute $\Ext(k,M)$ and $\Tor(k,M)$ and notice that you get the same complex

Comment: Automorphisms $f:R\to R$ act on $R$-modules as follows: if $M$ is an $R$-module, then $f(M)$ is the $R$-module which coincides with $M$ as an abelian group and on which $R$ acts so that $r\cdot m=f(r)m$ (on the right of the equal sign here we are using the original action of $R$ on $M$) This action is in fact by automorphisms of the category of modules, so that projective dimensions are preserved.

Answer (score 1):

One direction is **false**. Let me investigate this problem:

Over $k[x,y]$ free and projective is the same for finitely generated modules by Quillen-Suslin.

We have an exact sequence $$0 \to C \to F \to M \to 0,$$ where $F$ is free and $C$ is free if and only if the projective dimension of $M$ is strictly smaller than two.

Note that $F$ has $\mathfrak m$-depth two because it is free, hence $\operatorname{Hom}(k,F) = \operatorname{Ext}^1(k,F)=0$. The long exact sequence yields $\operatorname{Hom}(k,M) \cong \operatorname{Ext}^1(k,C)$.

If the projective dimension of $M$ is $<2$, then $C$ is free and the RHS is zero. This direction works fine.

If the projective dimension of $M$ is $2$, then $C$ is not free (but it is torsion-free as a submodule of $F$). So we would have to show that this implies $\operatorname{Ext}^1(k,C) \neq 0$. This is due to Auslander-Buchsbaum in the local case but in our non-local case this is false.

Choose $C$, s.t. $C$ is free at $\mathfrak m$ but not free at another maximal ideal of $R$. For instance let $C$ be the maximal ideal $\mathfrak n=(x,y-1)$. Then $C_\mathfrak m = R_\mathfrak m$ is free , but $C$ is not free. We can compute

$$\operatorname{Ext}^1_R(R/\mathfrak m,C)_\mathfrak m = \operatorname{Ext}^1_{R_\mathfrak m}(R/\mathfrak m,C_\mathfrak m) = 0,$$
since $C_\mathfrak m$ is free.
And for all other maximal ideals we have $(R/\mathfrak m)_{\mathfrak q} = 0$, so clearly $\operatorname{Ext}^1_R(R/\mathfrak m,C)_\mathfrak q =0$. Thus $\operatorname{Ext}^1_R(R/\mathfrak m,C)$ is zero, because it is locally zero.

This gives us a counterexample for $M$, namely $M = R/(x,y-1)$. It has projective dimension two (It cannot have projective dimension one, because its localization at $\mathfrak n$ has projective dimension two), but $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R/\mathfrak m,M)=0$.